# Blurry features while moving OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm using OpenLayers 6.0.1 (had the same problem on version 5) to display multiple features on the map. Everything is nice and sharp until I start moving map. The features look like that:

[image]

But when I will move the map they become blurry till I release the mouse button. Take a look:

[image]

Is that normal? Can I do something about it?

I'm defining `View` like this:

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([17, 52]),
    resolutions: tileLayer.tileSource.getTileGrid().getResolutions(),
    zoom: 3
})
```

I've read somewhere that missing `resolutions` could create such effect but this didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I just received the following answer from the OpenLayers team:

*This is by design. When the map image is static, we want a sharp image, so we snap the icons to an integer pixel. When the map is moving, we do not want the images to jump around, so we render them at the exact calculated position, which makes them blurry.*

And this is exactly answering my question.